# How to customize PatternLayout in JBOSS EAP 6.4

Tags: logging, jboss, migration, jboss6.x

My web application is running in Jboss EAP 5.2 and i have a customized PatternLayout for my logging. This CustomPatternLayout will identify couple of REGEX and replace appropriate content. For example if log data like "`Hello [World]`" then it becomes "`Hello *****`".

Now i am trying to migrate my server JBOSS EAP 5.2 to JBOSS EAP 6.4. I am facing difficulties with logging CustomPatternLayout.

My question is How to implement CustomPatternLayout in JBOSS EAP 6.4?

I did some workaround like Jboss logging handler having filter-spec substituteAll, this will identify regex and do replacement.

But the problem is, if i have more then one handler same replaced content spreading across to rest of handler.

Example: "`Hello [world]`" content logged in FILE1, FILE2, FILE3 handler. If I put my `filter-spec` in to FILE2 handler then my output become like below

```
FILE1: "Hello [world]"

FILE2: "Hello *****"

FILE3: "Hello *****"
```

Here FILE3 should be "`Hello [world]`"

Can somebody help in this?